# Contact form 7 plugin not working properly

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm using latest version of wordpress, contactform7 and POST SMTP plugin. I'm using Contactform 7 for contact us form. when i click on submit button then form data is submitted in the database but E-mail is not sent and also success message is not shown.I have checked in ajax response it showing me error which is as below :

code: "internal_server_error"
message: "

There has been a critical error on your website.

[Learn more about debugging in WordPress.](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/)

To resolve it I also try a solution but it's not working.Below is the link of it.

[Contact Form 7 cause HTTP 500 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47529257/contact-form-7-cause-http-500-error)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to downgrade WordPress version 4.9.8 . Install downgrade plugin so easily downgrade WordPress .

Comment: This is a best and safe way to downgrade using https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-downgrade/

Comment: @DipakDholakiya Is there any other way apart from downgrade wordpress version? because if I downgrade the wordpress version then it may impact on website.

Comment: Not any impact ion your website. I'll do many times using this plugin

Comment: So there is no other way apart from downgrade wordpress version?

Comment: is there live url of your issue ?

Comment: @NealDeveloper Yes.

Comment: You need install new WP otherwise try in local @DrashtiKorat

Comment: can share the live URL ?

Comment: To access the form Login credentials is required and sorry but we can't disclosed the credentials. It is confidential.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but can you check your live rewrite rules: in htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try below points

- Deactivate all of your plugins –

does the issue still exist? If not, activate each plugin one by one until the issue happens again.

- Turn on WP DEBUG – do any errors display in your Dashboard or on your live site?
- If you’re getting a white screen while Customizing or somewhere else, try increasing your memory limit.
- Activate the core WordPress theme (TwentySeventeen) – does the issue still exist? If so, we know it’s not a GeneratePress specific issue.
- Check your error_log (or ask your hosting to) – are there any big errors in there?